# libssh logging callback ssh_set_log_callback()

Tags: c++, libssh

I am writing an application which uses libssh, which logs to stderr by default. I would like to capture the logging to so I can do something useful with it.

Libssh provides some functions seemingly for this purpose, but I can't seem to get them to work. The documentation is limited and I can't seem to find much out there.

The function provided in libssh/callbacks.h is `int ssh_set_log_callback ( ssh_logging_callback cb )` documented [here](http://api.libssh.org/stable/group__libssh__log.html#ga6accdc08b7d8c4234750ef30c4854b9e).

`ssh_logging_callback` is documented [here](http://api.libssh.org/stable/group__libssh__callbacks.html#ga9c9831925f10b1dbec582127f4d4170e)

I have the following code in my app:

```
static void ssh_log_function(int priority, const char *function, const char *buffer, void *userdata)
{
    cout << priority << " " << function << endl << buffer << endl;
    cout << "And now for something completely different" << endl;
}
```

Then later in my app, before I execute some libssh commands, I have this:

```
ssh_set_log_callback(ssh_log_function);
```

When I compile and execute, I get the usual logging output to stderr and no sign of the function I created running.

Have I missed something or am I doing it completely wrong? I have tried passing &ssh_log_function as well but it didn't make any difference.

Would appreciate any help! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone interested, I managed to get this working and the above code works. I was simply setting the log level to an uninitialised integer later on in my code. /Fail

Hope this helps someone else.